# Pyqt English to Finnish Translation

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I want to convert the langauge of pyqt application from english to finnish . I saw that pyqt has some methods for it and i try to use it but it didnt help me

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
translator = QtCore.QTranslator()
translator.load("qt_fr.qm")
app.installTranslator(translator)
```

.qm file is present at right path (right now its taking french i guess) and on button i use this text

```
 name = "File"
 button.setText(self.tr(QtCore.QString(name)))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you are mixing two things: the translations of Qt itself (which are provided via qt_xx.qm files and distributed along with Qt) and your own translations.

Here you have an example using the russian translation file of Qt itself:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.myButtons = QDialogButtonBox(self)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.myButtons)
        button = self.myButtons.addButton(QDialogButtonBox.Open)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    translator = QTranslator()
    print translator.load("qt_ru", QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath))
    app.installTranslator(translator)
    ui = MyWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you need your own translations then the *Produce translations* section of the [i18n with Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/internationalization.html#produce-translations) can be of help to you. You will need to provide a project file, your translation files (.ts) and use the Qt Linguist tool.

You can mix both the Qt itself translation and your own app translation by installing multiple translators.

Please note that when loading the translator you don't have to add the .qm extension to the filename.

Comment: thanks for the reply . It helps me just clear me one thing if i write a text in a label , can i able to translate it with qt itself ? or do i have to write my own translations . Thanks

Comment: You have to write your own translation.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the Qt Manual on Translation or just have a look at a very basic yet illustrative example here: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/linguist-hellotr.html. Please note: you may need to provide the translation files yourself using f.i. [Qt Linguist](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/linguist-translators.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this inside your window's `__init__()`, you **must** save (retain a reference to) your translator:

```
self.translator = translator
```

Otherwise your translator will get garbage-collected, even after installation. In that case, `self.tr()` will stop working (fails silently).